# Decrescent range of year for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, select

What I have

```
options_for_select(1995..Date.today.year)
```

What I want in a brute force manner

```
options_for_select((1995..Date.today.year).to_a.reverse)
```

How can I rewrite the second `options_for_select` without having to reverse the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `downto` instead:

```
options_for_select(Date.today.year.downto(1995))
```